# Phonegap 3.4: error ITM-9000 when distribute app to app store

Tags: ios, cordova

I got an error when I was trying to upload my app to iOS app store. They show me the error like this.

[image]

Before I upload the app to store, I use command line

```
phonegap build ios
```

Then they generated new files in platforms/ios, after that, I clicked .xcodeproj file to open my project in Xcode.

I test my app on device simulator and it works fine on every iOS device. Then I archive my app to prepare it to be uploaded to app store. But during its uploading, it shows me the error ITMS-9000.

This is my config file in phonegapProject/www/config.xml

[image]

and my project in Xcode

[image]

project files structure.

[image]

any help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your product Info in Launch images section if you have "No image specified" in for some screens, please provide appropriate screens for them. Or you can use a asset catalogue to include splash screens and icons.